# Mint from V3 candy machine using Umi. Throws Anchor error - account not insitialised

Tags: metaplex, solana-wallet-adapter, candy-machine-v3

I have used the Sugar CLI to upload a test candy machine with just 2 items and the collection data, and then set up a simple mintLimit guard.

Am am able to find the candyMachine and see all of the info for both it and the candyGuard using umi. However when I try to mint from it, I get an error.

This is my front end code:

```
    import { useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
    import { FC } from 'react';
    import { notify } from 'utils/notifications';
    import { mintV2, mplCandyMachine, fetchCandyMachine } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine";
    import { setComputeUnitLimit } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-toolbox";
    import { transactionBuilder, generateSigner, publicKey, some } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
    import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";
    import { walletAdapterIdentity } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-signer-wallet-adapters';
    
    export const Nfts: FC = () => {
        
        const wallet = useWallet();
        const mintNFT = async () => {
    
            notify({ message: 'Minting NFT', description: 'Please wait...' });
    
            const umi = createUmi("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
                .use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet))
                .use(mplCandyMachine());
    
            const candyMachinePublicKey = publicKey("xxx---MyCandyMachineKeyHere---xxx");
            const candyMachine = await fetchCandyMachine(umi, candyMachinePublicKey);
            const nftMint = generateSigner(umi);
    
            await transactionBuilder()
                .add(setComputeUnitLimit(umi, { units: 1_000_000 }))
                .add(
                    mintV2(umi, {
                        candyMachine: candyMachine.publicKey,
                        nftMint,
                        collectionMint: candyMachine.collectionMint,
                        collectionUpdateAuthority: candyMachine.authority,
                        mintArgs: {
                            mintLimit: some({ id: 1 }),
                        },
                    })
                )
                .sendAndConfirm(umi);
        };
    
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="relative group items-center">
                    <div className="m-1 absolute -inset-0.5 bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-500 to-fuchsia-500 
                                                    rounded-lg blur opacity-20 group-hover:opacity-100 transition duration-1000 group-hover:duration-200 animate-tilt"></div>
                    <button
                        className="px-8 m-2 btn animate-pulse bg-gradient-to-br from-indigo-500 to-fuchsia-500 hover:from-white hover:to-purple-300 text-black"
                        onClick={() => mintNFT()}
                    >
                        <span>Dummy Mint</span>
                    </button>
    
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

The error I get is from the candy_guard program.

```
Uncaught (in promise) ProgramErrorNotRecognizedError: The program [mplCandyGuard] at address [Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g] raised an error that is not recognized by the programs registered on the SDK. Please check the underlying program error below for more details.

Source: Program > mplCandyGuard [Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g]

Caused By: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xbc4

Program Logs:
| Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
| Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success
| Program Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g invoke [1]
| Program log: Instruction: MintV2
| Program log: AnchorError caused by account: candy_guard. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized.
| Program Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g consumed 9739 of 1000000 compute units
| Program Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g failed: custom program error: 0xbc4

    at Object.y [as resolveError] (229-6a6ac4f97ae95025.js:12:1770)
    at Object.b [as sendTransaction] (229-6a6ac4f97ae95025.js:12:6206)
    at async o.sendAndConfirm (229-6a6ac4f97ae95025.js:12:34106)
```

Does anyone know if I'm giving the correct information to the MintV2 instruction there, or if there's anything else I need to attend to before attempting the mint? I've no idea which account it's referring to that it expected to be intialiased. Maybe it's something I can pre-init.

Or is there a preferred method for using v3 machines with a front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was an extra parameter which is not mentioned in the documentation.

```
            .add(
                mintV2(umi, {
                    candyMachine: candyMachine.publicKey,
                    nftMint,
                    collectionMint: candyMachine.collectionMint,
                    collectionUpdateAuthority: candyMachine.authority,
                    candyGuard: candyMachine.mintAuthority, // This extra param
                    mintArgs: {
                        mintLimit: some({ id: 1 }),
                    },
                })
            )
```

The candgyGuard option take the mintAuthority as it's value, and this succesfully minted.